# full calendar events appearing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

After creating an event the style remains. But sometimes the events appear to be duplicated. The jquery code and screen shots are attached for better understanding.

[image]

this is how the events look after loading from backend

this is my jquery functions

```
select: function (start, end) {
                        var title = "Available";
                        var eventData;
                        if (title) {
                            eventData = {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end
                            };
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true

                            createEvent(eventData);

                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                location.reload()
                            }, 300);

                            $.notifyBar({
                                cssClass: "WARNING",
                                html: "Created Successfully."
                            });
                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

                    },

    eventSources: [{
                    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                        var employeeId = $("#employee-Id").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '../' + employeeId + '/events',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (response) {
                                var events = $.parseJSON(response.data);
                                callback(events);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }],
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    //delete event on double click..Tanvir
                    element.unbind("dblclick").one().bind('dblclick', function (e) {

                        $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format(' DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm'));
                        $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm'));

                        $("#eventContent").dialog({modal: true, title: event.title, width: 100});

                        $('.delete-event').unbind("click").click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                            deleteEvent(event.id);
                            $("#eventContent").hide();

                        });

                        $('.discard-delete').bind('click', function () {
                            $("#eventContent").hide();
                        });
                    });

    function createEvent(eventData) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(function () {
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                                },
                                url: '../availability/create',
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                type: 'GET',
                                traditional: true,
                                data: {
                                  eventsJson:JSON.stringify(eventData),
                                  id: $("#employee-Id").val()
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (response) {
                                },
                                error: function (xhr) {

                                }

                            });
                    });
                });
            }
```

this is all about i can provide.Please feel free to ask if you need more info

Comment: It's unclear to me what the issue is. As far as I can see, what you've got there in the first screenshot is simply two events occurring on the same date and time. How you created them, I don't know - either your event feed from the server, or your "select" callback might have done it. Did you go through some particular process which causes them to appear like that? If so, please clarify. Perhaps there's an issue server-side where things are being duplicated.

Comment: BTW 1) why are you calling location.reload() after you create an event? It seems a bit unnecessary to refresh the whole page, just because you added an event into the calendar. What does that achieve?

Comment: and 2) .bind() and .unbind() were superseded by better functions .on() and .off() all the way back in jQuery 1.7 - you should not be using those functions in new code. They are now officially deprecated too, so you can expect them to stop working completely in a future upgrade. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) for details

Comment: i used location.reload() for some special purpose such as validationg if there is already exisitng availability then just reload the page and not creating that availability.

Comment: i used bind and unbind to prevent double click problem. and i m using jquery 3

Comment: i load events from server side.

Comment: I know _why_ you use bind and unbind. I'm telling you though that you should be using on and off for that purpose instead. Like I said, read the documentation, you'll see that bind and unbind have been replaced.

Comment: "such as validationg if there is already exisitng availability"...ok but you could do that with ajax if you wanted. My point was if you're just going to refresh the page immediately, then doing `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);` is pointless because that will not survive the reload. Also since you reload so fast, there's also a small chance your "createEvents" function will not have time to finish, if it is making a background ajax call. It's a risky approach, and seemingly unnecessary.

Comment: "i load events from server side". I know you do, that's clear from the code and my first comment already noted it. That's not the issue. The issue is how it's coming to duplicate your events. Your code above does not, by itself, demonstrate how that's happening. So I was trying to ask you to give more information, and maybe do some more investigation, if need be.

Comment: I've edited your question to give a better description of what is happening. It's not a style issue, it's a duplicate event problem. If you say this is happening after you create events, then I would debug your event creation code very carefully (both on client and server). I do wonder if the page reloading is somehow contributing to the problem - it's an odd thing to want to do. You didn't show us your server code, or your "createEvent" JavaScript code, which both might be important to the issue.

Comment: yes this is happening after creation of events.

Comment: the create event ajax function is attached herewith @ADyson

Comment: Ok thanks. First thing to say is that within createEvents, `$(document).ready(function () {
                    $(function () {` is completely not necessary. These two things both do the same thing, and are both to stop code running until the page has fully loaded. But since they're inside a function already, the code can only run when the function is called. This is basic jQuery - you should try to understand what the code is when you use it.

Comment: Anyway there is nothing else obviously wrong with that createEvents code. Next I would try to debug your server code, if I was you. Check what data it is adding to the database, and what JSON it is generating when it retrieves the events.